# Different transitions for parent view and child views: SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, transition

I'm trying to add "Transition A" to the parent view and "Transition B" to it's child view in SwiftUI but I'm unable to do so, because the child view in SwiftUI always follows the parent's transition.

UPDATE: sample code
Can I do something like this ?

```
struct ParentView: View {
var body: some View {
ScrollView {
ForEach(items) { item in // items is a struct with properties name & city
ChildView(item: item).transition(.slide)
     }
   }
  }
}

struct ChildView: View {
var item: JSON
var body: some View {
VStack {
Text("Name: \(item.name)").transition(scale)
Text("City: \(item.city)").transition(scale)
    }
  }
}
```

How do I achieve this ? Any help would be great cuz I have been struggling with this forever.

Comment: Please include a minimum reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to allow others to help you more effectively.

Comment: I have added a sample code. Thank you.